# When can tags be changed during edit?

Tags: support, editing

A user posted a question on a modem and tagged it as [software-recommendation]. I would like to change that to [usb-modem] plus [hardware], but am not allowed. Why is it so? Who can change tags? Moderators only? Can tag editing be made possible to users at my level of reputation?

Comment: Please post the link to the question.

Comment: Someone probably had an edit suggested when you tried to edit.

Comment: Seth is probably correct, I was able to change the tags today.

Answer (score 1):

Tag edits and other edits can be performed by anyone with sufficient rep to do so.  See [this](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges).